# Firebird - Way to determine delete occurred from constrained or not inside trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

Is there a way to determine delete occurred from using constrained with cascade delete or not inside trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - when a row is deleted then appropriate triggers will fire but there is no "context" what caused the delete. However, in the `AFTER DELETE` trigger you can check does the master record exist - if it doesn't then there is a good chance that the delete is triggered by the `ON DELETE CASCADE` constaraint and not because user issued "direct" `DELETE` on the row.